# Prestashop 1.7 Customer Order history cart problem

Tags: prestashop, cart, shopping-cart

I have a problem with PrestaShop 1.7 order history page. My last ordered items is loaded in shopping cart but this happens only in the customer order history page.

Thanks.

Comment: Question is very unclear. Order history is only for completed orders, don't understand the relation to the shopping cart (which is for *un*completed orders)

Comment: @defuzed yes you are right, customer history page are completed orders. But problem is whenever I go to this page last ordered items are being count and displayed by shopping cart module and the weird thing is when I go back to home page and other pages cart quantity becomes normal. Also when cart has items everything is normal.

Comment: by "displayed by shopping cart module" you mean the items of that specific order detail are being shown in the shopping cart? Sounds like an issue with your theme (i'm guessing you're using a theme since default PS 1.7 doesn't have shopping cart "mouseover" where you could see the contents of the cart) and more specifically some JS issue where elements of order detail are being loaded into the cart. Just some guesses...

Comment: Okay thanks @defuzed i'll check it later

Comment: @defuzed I already solve the problem, the problem is on prestashop argument params, its sending the id_cart and cart presenter is using this data to fetch it from database and displays it, so what I did is just ignore this params and use the cookie id_cart instead. id_cart in cookie is removed once order is completed. thanks for your help. appreciate it.